# Working with the command prompt in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, .net-4.5

I am working on a project of remotely receiving commands from a server, but I am facing a problem when working with the command prompt locally. Once I get it working locally, then I will move to remote communication.

**Problem:**

1. I have to completely hide the console, and client must not see any response when the client is working with the command line but it will show a console for a instance and then hide it.
2. I had to use c# to send a command to `cmd.exe` and receive the result back in C#. I have done it in one way by setting the StandardOutput... and input to true.
3. The commands are not working.  For example, `D:` should change the directory to D and it does, but after that, if we use `dir` to see the directories in D, it does not show the appropriate directories.

Here is my code:

**First Method**

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + textBoxInputCommand.Text + " >> " + " system";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

**Second Method**

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + textBoxInputCommand.Text);
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
richTextBoxCommandOutput.Text += result;
```

I want the program to run as administrator because the exe it generates does not run commands when it runs from the C drive.

Comment: Executing `cmd /c d:` changes the working directory to D: *for that instance of cmd.exe.* But then that instance exits and the next time you run cmd.exe, the directory will be the same as the current working directory of your program.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: there's no such thing as a "DOS prompt" unless you're running Windows 98. It's the Windows Command Prompt. DOS hasn't existed in Windows for 15 years.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try not to run the commands by passing them to `cmd` instead write the commands passed by the client to a`.bat` file execute the `.bat.` file from your program this will probably hide your command prompt window.
2. You can also use `process.OutputDataRecieved` event handler to do anything with the output.
3. If you want to execute command using administrator rights you can use `runas`command. It is equivalent to the `sudo` command in `Linux`. Here is a piece of code may be it will help you

   ```
    var process = new Process();
    var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\users\Shashwat\Desktop\test.bat");
    startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = startinfo;
    process.OutputDataRecieved += DoSomething;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    //Event Handler
    public void DoSomething(object sener, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
          //Do something
    }
   ```

   Hope it helps you.

Comment: runas didnt work when useing shell option is set to true. is there other way to add the installer to a registery

Comment: Please clear to me that whether you want your cmd commands to run with admin privileges or you want your c# program to run with admin privileges when installed.

Comment: definitely not my cmd, i want the c# program to run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

You could **hide** command prompt window by adding this line of code:

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

or **do not create** it at all

```
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Here can be found a few awarding solutions:
[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)